# Namespace name Authentication does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

Tags: c#, .net-standard

From this page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1#httpclient-and-httprequestmessage-with-fetch-api-request-options
why is it that

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
```

isn't found? Authentication is missing from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly`

My target framework is .NET Standard 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem as well:

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication // not found
```

When I added `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` the package was found:

**Client.csproj**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal" Version="5.0.4" />
```

**LoginDisplay.razor**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication // found
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your OP was 4 months ago I'm guessing you went with the latest NUGET package which likely was NET 5 compatible however you state you are using .NET Standard 2.1.

Downgrade you Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication to 3.2.1 and it should work or upgrade your project to Net 5.